# Debugger tools not working in firefox and chrome (no stored variables exist)

Tags: jquery, iframe, console.log

Hi i start with the error i get and then some code that should fire up in the developer tool with its value:

2414:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: 'ANYTHING' is not defined

the code

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
var text = $('.ceb');
//$('.text').css({ 'display' : 'none'});
var base = $('html').children().get(1);
    
base = $(base).children().get(1);

    
base = $(base)[0].contentWindow.document;
$(base).contents().find('.container');
console.log($(base));
```

futhermore if i go to the developer tool it always shows LIKE the var text undefined strange error could mean that traversing in iframe not work i know how to do it but is my pc corrupted? cuz it worked before,, the question on its own be:  How is it that ive got no variables stored?

I tried to get a element tag from a iframe but since it doesnt know any variables its not succeeding all at a sudden